# extends class Proc smth wrong Ruby

Tags: ruby

i have been written code which for me is correct but for some reason that doesnt work

```
class Funkcja < Proc
   def value(x)
     self.call(x)
   end
end


f = Proc.new {|x| x*x*Math.sin(x)}
puts f.value(2)
```

Error what i got is undefined method `value' for #

Comment: having class/method/variable/etc names in languages other than English is a code smell :)

Answer (score 2):

It's highly unusual to derive from Proc, but if you want to, then that's fine. You just need to use the class you've created:

```
f = Funkcja.new {|x| x*x*Math.sin(x)}
```

The `class F < Proc` declaration does not *extend* Proc, it creates a subclass.

It's odd here because all you're doing is creating an alias for the `call` method. You can do that with `alias_method` just the same:

```
class Funkcja < Proc
  alias_method :value, :call
end
```

Comment: so how can i do it withoud derive from Proc. Methods what i have to write are .value(x), .zero(a,b,e) .area(a,b) .derivative(x)

Comment: This answers your immediate question. What you're asking now is a new question and should be set up as such. You'll also have to explain what you mean by those things.

Comment: Could u just tell me how extend class Proc?

Comment: It could require a lot of explanation depending on what you're talking about. Open up a new question to address this issue. I got your original code working.